# Angular 6 guards blocking even when it shoundn't

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular-router-guards

I'm having a problem with angular 6 route guard. When I hit the login button, it won't redirect me to the intended route.
My html calls the `login()` function, while the `loginService.isAutenticated` returns `true` when the `doLogin()` method is executed, it returns `false` in the guard itself.

**loginComponent.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '../common/user.model';
import { LoginService } from './login.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
  providers: [LoginService]
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  private usuario: User = new User();
  msg: string;

  constructor(private service: LoginService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  login() {
   this.service.fazerLogin(this.usuario);
  }

  limpar() {
    this.usuario.nome = '';
    this.usuario.senha = '';
  }

}
```

**loginService.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '../common/user.model';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


@Injectable()
export class LoginService {

  url = 'api';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
              private router: Router
             ) { }

  isAuthenticated = false;

  doLogin(user: User) {

    if (user.name === 'admin' && user.pass === 'admin') {
      this.isAuthenticated = true;
      this.router.navigate(['/principal']);

    } else {
      console.log('Auth Failed');
    }
  }

  userIsAuthenticated() {
    return this.isAuthenticated;
  }
}
```

**app.routes.ts**

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { PrincipalComponent } from './principal/principal.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
import { PendenciasComponent } from './pendencias/pendencias.component';
import { TesteComponent } from './teste/teste.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './guards/auth.guard';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: LoginComponent},
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'principal', component: PrincipalComponent,
      canActivate: [AuthGuard],
      children: [
        { path: 'pendencias', component: PendenciasComponent,
          canActivate: [AuthGuard]
        },
        { path: 'teste', component: TesteComponent,
          canActivate: [AuthGuard]
        },

      ]
    },
    { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
  ];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

**auth.guard.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, CanActivateChild, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { LoginService } from '../login/login.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor (private loginService: LoginService,
               private router: Router
              ) {}


  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
      // if (this.loginService.usuarioEstaAutenticado()) {
      if (this.loginService.isAuthenticated) {
        console.log('canActivate retornou true');

        return true;
      }
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      console.log(this.loginService.isAuthenticated);

      console.log('canActivate retornou false');
      return false;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't make the loginService be provided by the component if you need to inject it in the auth guard also. If you do that, your service will be not singleton and I think here you expect the instance to be shared between the component and the guard. Make the LoginService provided by the Module

Comment: Ah great :), feel free to mark (or not) this as the answer to close the subject